# List USB devices (with more details than lsusb)

Tags: usb-device, lsusb

I've not been able to get the same information from `lsusb` as I can extract from the journal (system-log).

This is from the system-log:

```
Jun 08 12:23:04 SRV01 kernel: usb 1-5: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
Jun 08 12:23:06 SRV01 kernel: usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0463, idProduct=ffff,     bcdDevice= 1.00
Jun 08 12:23:06 SRV01 kernel: usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
Jun 08 12:23:06 SRV01 kernel: usb 1-5: Product: Eaton 3S
Jun 08 12:23:06 SRV01 kernel: usb 1-5: Manufacturer: EATON
Jun 08 12:23:06 SRV01 kernel: usb 1-5: SerialNumber: 000000000
Jun 08 12:23:09 SRV01 kernel: hid-generic 0003:0463:FFFF.0003: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v10.10 Device [EATON Eaton 3S] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
```

Is there another way to retrieve these information other than from the system-log?
I guess you cannot rely on the information will always be present in the log (e.g. log-rotation).

Comment: How much more detail do you need than `lsusb` provides?  You can get much more than that, just from `lsusb -vvv -d 0463:ffff` (if you run it as root, so that you can obtain the string descriptors).

Comment: Have you tried `lsusb -v (or --verbose)`?

Comment: You're right. I did actually try this command at first but I missed the `iManufacturer`, `iProduct` and `iSerial` fields but I see now that they are there, thanks.